# parse git status log and exit if modified files are from a given directory

Tags: regex, shell, perl

I have written following script to throw an error if the modified files in `git status` is from `directory_3`. Now I want to enhance this script to exit if the files are modified in any directory except: `directory_1/path/to/dir_1/` and `directory_2/path/to/dir_1/`.
I'm not able to script how to ignore the first two and last three lines of `git status` log (`git_status.log`) shown below. How can i modify the `if condition` to ignore all directories except the two mentioned above.

**INITIAL_SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "/home/user/git_status.log";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    #print "INFO: $row \n";

    if(grep(/\bdirectory_3\b/, $row))
    {
        print "INFO: This is an error case. Exit now \n";
        print ">>> $row \n";
        exit 1;
    }
}
```

**INPUT_FILE**

```
$> cat git_status.log

On branch development_branch
Changes to be committed:

    modified:   directory_1/path/to/dir_1/file1.txt
    modified:   directory_1/path/to/dir_2/file2.txt
    new file:   directory_2/path/to/dir_1/file3.txt
    modified:   directory_2/path/to/dir_2/file4.txt
    new file:   directory_3/path/to/dir_2/file5.txt
    modified:   directory_3/path/to/dir_2/file6.txt

It took 3.92 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to enhance your regex to ignore those lines. You can use the below to identify the lines that are starting with `modified:` or `new file:` and those do *not* contain the allowed paths you have provided. This way if the regex hits some results your condition gets true and you can throw an error as you have shown in the OP

```
if( grep { ( (/\b(modified|new file):/ ) and ( !/((directory_1|directory_2)\/path\/to\/dir_1)/) ) } $row )
```

Instead of dumping the result of `git status` to a file and parsing it later, for a quick check on the command-line, you can pipe the status output to

```
perl -le 'print grep{/\b(modified|new file):/ && !/((directory_1|directory_2)\/path\/to\/dir_1)/}<>'
```